# Make a copy of the pdf file using lua

Tags: luatex, luacode

I would like to make a copy of the pdf file, but the following command (just before `\end{document}`) doesn't work.

```
\directlua{os.execute("cp \jobname.pdf \jobname_bis.pdf")}
```

My aim is the following (after the tex execution) :

- make a copy of the pdf file (called `\jobname_bis.pdf`),
- next move the file in another folder. The command `\directlua{os.rename("\jobname_bis.pdf", "Another_folder/\jobname.pdf")}` works perfectly.

Comment: you could run this in the `wrapup_run` callback which is called after the PDF is closed. The full documentation of this in the luatex manual is: "Use it at your own risk"

Comment: why don't you do this in a simple script that is called that wraps the call to luatex?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just add some details about my intentions.

Comment: Because I would like to do this copy just if and only if a certain tex boolean value is equal to true. So, I think that I need to put this commands in the main tex document.

Comment: I think the pdf is opened for writing as soon as \jobname is fixed so I don't think it's possible, may be proved wrong though:-)

Comment: if you always copied the file before starting, your tex code could conditionally delete the copy or move it to the final location.

Comment: but I'm confused by your edit, you say you tried the copy before end{document}. At that point the original pdf is certainly over-written, and you could use the wrapup_run callback to do the copy later when it's closed, but from your added descriptiuon it seems you want to copy the original file at the _start_ of the run?

Comment: I would like to make the copy and the moving after the execution